# Grouping by datetime column and keeping the averages

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL and facing an issue here. I think I understand what I might need to do but not the Syntax for it. Basically I have a large amount of counts by hour and I need to take all those hourly counts and join them together to display by day rather than by hour and then take the average of the entire days count. I also needed to sort out which of these days were weekdays and exclude weekends... which I think I've done correctly but I could be wrong on this. If there's a more efficient way of doing so, please let me know!

```
  SELECT DatePart(WEEKDAY, [EVENT_TIME]) as DayoftheWeek
,[EVENT_TIME]
,[COUNT]
,[CLASS_SCHEME_ID]
,[CLASS_NUM]
,[ERROR_CODE]
,[REC_ENTRY_TIME]
FROM [SAMPLE_DATA].[dbo].[651511]
WHERE [EVENT_TIME] >= '2009-01-01' AND DatePart(WEEKDAY, [EVENT_TIME]) >=2 AND DatePart(WEEKDAY, [EVENT_TIME]) <= 6
GROUP BY ,[EVENT_TIME]
,[COUNT]
,[CLASS_SCHEME_ID]
,[CLASS_NUM]
,[ERROR_CODE]
,[REC_ENTRY_TIME]
GO
```

I've been reading about what I might need to do... something about casting maybe? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you were wanting a lower granularity than Day (ie class), but if not I think this should get you there.  If you would like more granularity in your result, add those fields to both your select and your group by.

This will also take into account any non-default setting of @@DateFirst

```
SELECT
    DatePart(Weekday, event_time) as DayName,
    avg(count) as DayAvg
FROM
    sample_date.dbo.651511
WHERE 
    event_time >= '2009-01-01' and
    (DATEPART(dw, date_created) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
Group by
    DatePart(Weekday, event_time)
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for this! It's almost right but on line 8 I keep getting a syntax error at ',' (which I believe is the first ',' in the DATEPART function. Not sure why this is. Also it appears after running 

`SELECT @@VERSION` 

that I have SQL 2005 running... someone had told me it was 2008. Not sure how much of a difference that makes.

Comment: @MatthewPaxman: This query does have issues but they have nothing to do with either commas or the version of SQL Server (at least, once the issues are fixed, the query should run in SQL Server 2005 as fine as in SQL Server 2008). The issues are: 1) the table name not delimited, 2) the DATEPART expression in WHERE missing two opening brackets at the beginning, 3) the backtick at the end of the query. Also the GROUP BY list in your query *starts* with a comma. That may be a typo, like the backtick in this query, but it might accidentally have made its way into the query that you were trying.